# Identifying a WW2 German badge/medal

Tags: world-war-two, military, nazi-germany

Is anyone able to identify this? It appears to be a part of a badge as there is a leather backing on it. [image]

Comment: It's a badge from the 1939 NSDAP [East Hanover Gau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau_Eastern_Hanover) rally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a NSDAP commemorative badge that commemorates a rally held in 1939 in [Gau Eastern Hannover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau_Eastern_Hanover), as Steve Bird mentioned. Here's a link to a [site](https://hb-militaria.de/english/orden/orden-1933-1945/tinnies-and-daybadges/ost-hannover-gautag.html) that sells the same piece.

The NSDAP was rather prolific with this type of cheap commemorative item, making them for many rallies, events or other instances. Theses type of badges are sometimes referred to as a [tinnie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinnie).